# If a child of an element is empty add class to another child of that element

Tags: jquery

I have an element containing two divs.

This is the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        text...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image_right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If "image_right" is empty i need to change the class or css of col-md-9

This is the code

```
$('.row').each(function() {
if ( $.trim( $(this).children.text() ).length == 0 ) {
    if ( $(this).children().length == 0 ) {
        $(this).text('');
         $(this).remove();

         $(this).sibling.css('float', 'left');


    }
}
});
```

but it is not working.

Comment: If you give us the associated HTML I'm fairly certain there's a better solution

Comment: I added the html

Comment: I'm looking at this with the html you added but I will tell you that you are calling many properties that are not defined, such as `$(this).children` and `$(this).sibling`. Check your browser console and many of your problems will be pointed out to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following jquery but maybe it could be simpler:

```
   $('.image_right').each(function() {
   if ( $.trim( $(this).text() ).length == 0 ) {
       if ( $(this).children().length == 0 ) {
           $(this).text('');
            $(this).remove(); // remove empty paragraphs
       }
   }
});  
$('.col-md-3').each(function() {
   if ( $.trim( $(this).text() ).length == 0 ) {
       if ( $(this).children().length == 0 ) {
        $(this).text('');
         $(this).remove(); // remove empty paragraphs
    }
}
});  

$('.views-row .row').each(function() {
if(!$(this).children('.col-md-3').length) {

$(this).find('.col-md-9').addClass('no_image');
 }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will accomplish what you want to do.

```js
$('.row').children().each(function(i,e) {
  let $e = $(e);
  if ( $e.find(".image_right").length !== 0 ) {
    $e.siblings().css('background-color', 'purple');
    $e.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.row{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        text...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image_right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a few of these rows and this applies to all the rows i want only the rows which have an empty image_right to have the css applied to col-md-9

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()` and `siblings()`

```js
$('.image_right').filter(function() {
  return !this.textContent.trim()
}).parent().siblings().css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    text...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="image_right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a few of these rows and this applies to all the rows i want only the rows which have an empty image_right to have the css applied to col-md-9

Comment: This will loop over all of them